# Could not remove buildType in AndroidStudio 1.0 RC

Tags: android, eclipse, build, gradle, android-studio

Could not remove buildType in `AndroidStudio 1.0 RC`(there is nothing in gradle scripts about this set) as shown:

[image]

Any idea why?

Checked that other projects has no `Build Types` set and run properly.

Comment: AFAIK, those two build types are part of standard Gradle/Gradle for Android and cannot be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The release and debug build types are built-in; you can't remove them. Even if you go into your build scripts and remove them, they're part of your project by default. This behavior is designed into the Android Gradle plugin.